# Error message installing Cairo package in R

Tags: r

I want to install the Cairo package in R using:

```
install.packages("Cairo")
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The error message is following:

```
xlib-backend.c:34:74: fatal error: X11/Intrinsic.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [xlib-backend.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Cairo’
* removing ‘/home/magnus/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Cairo’
```

Does anybody have an answer for this problem? I couldn't find any help in the internet so far.

Many thanks in advance!

Yours,

broesel

Comment: Try this [link]. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437246/unable-to-install-cairo-package-under-linux). Make sure that to have X11 installed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need the development header as the file Intrinsic.h is not found.

For the related package cairoDevice (which I maintain for Debian), I ensure the following is installed:

```
libgtk2.0-dev, libcairo2-dev, xvfb, xauth, xfonts-base
```

If you are on a different distribution these might be called something else. The key is that the Gtk and Cairo header packages also pull in other, needed, x11 packages.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer, although I doubt that I fully understand what you meant. I am using Ubuntu. I made sure that all of `libgtk2.0-dev, libcairo2-dev, xvfb, xauth, xfonts-base` are installed, but the error remained. I didn't really git the second part of your answer. What does that mean and which consequences does that have for my further actions? Thank you...

Comment: It helps that you shared the fact that you use Ubuntu. Intrinsic.h is contained in the package `libxt-dev` which should have been installed with the other ones. Make sure you also have `r-base-dev` installed.

Comment: `r-base-dev` is installed, but `libxt-dev` wasn't. After installing `libxt-dev` I was able to install Cairo in R. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. You can use packages.ubuntu.com to search for packages given a filename. Helpful when missing headers like here.

Comment: For anyone else using Centos the package that provides Intrinsic.h is `libXt-devel`

Answer (score 33):

For me (Ubuntu 15.04) installing `libxt-dev` solved the problem.

(I know it's mentioned in comments above, but thought it might be good to have it in answers as well)

Answer (score 11):

`libXt-devel` needs to be installed in Fedora (25):

```
sudo dnf install libXt-devel
```

Comment: Same on Amazon Linux 2.

Answer (score 9):

On a Mac, my problems were solved once I installed libxt

```
brew install libxt
```

Similar, I'm sure to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41455437/61728

Answer (score 5):

Along with the packages `libgtk2.0-dev`, `libcairo2-dev`, `xvfb`, `xfonts-base` and `xauth` that Dirk mentioned in the above comment , I also installed `libxt-dev` (after Magnus' comment) after which I was able to install Cairo in R. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: This option worked for me too. I installed packages in the Terminal window in Ubuntu 20.04. I also added `libxt-dev` package before installing `Cairo` from R environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble with this, for some reason this didn't work

```bash
apt-get install libx11-dev libxt-dev libgtk2.0-dev libcairo2-dev xvfb xauth xfonts-base -y
```

but when I ran this immediately afterwards (even though it was already installed above), then the Cairo R package installed successfully. Not exactly sure why but thought I'd put it here in case it helps someone.

```
apt-get install libcairo2-dev -y
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
devtools::install_github("jcassiojr/BayesPeak")
```

then:

```
library("BayesPeak")
```

And worked.
Paulo